# Laravel update different database table

Tags: laravel

I have a controller in Laravel that is adding a 'room' to the database, like this...

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Room;


class SitesController extends Controller
{


    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
        ]);

        /* Create Post */
        $room = new Room;
        $room->name = $request->input('name');
        $room->save();

        return redirect('/room')->with('success', 'Room Created');
    }


}
```

This works great but I would also like to write something to a different database table.  Am I locked in to only updating the 'rooms' table in this controller or is there a way to modify others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking

> to write something to a different database table,

not into a totally different database, right?

Why would you think you are locked in? Just use another Model that represents the table you want to update as well.

```
use App\YourOtherModel;

...

/* Create Post */
$room = new Room;
$room->name = $request->input('name');
$room->save();

$other = new YourOtherModel;

... go ahead

$other->save();
```

Comment: I had tried that approach but as soon as I add 'use App\YourOtherModel'; I get 'htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string'

Comment: You have to use a model that exists though, are you adding 'App\YourOtherModel' literally?